# Price elasticity in logistic regression with log price

Tags: logistic, econometrics, logit, elasticity, logarithm

I'm estimating demand and calculating price elasticity using logistic regression.

In logistic regression with level price, elasticity is 
$$ \alpha*price*(1-share)$$
while if one uses log of price, elasticity is
$$ \alpha * (1-share) $$
I've noticed that if I estimate regression using level price, my elasticities vary highly within products. However, when I use log of price, elasticities for different products are very close to each other. I understand that it is because I have 22 products, and thus shares are very small and elasticities are mostly driven by $\alpha$.

Could someone please explain me on a high level why this happens. And should I use the regression with level price if I do not trust the elasticity estimates of the log price regression?

Comment: I am not sure if your derivation is correct. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147630/7071) for the log price case. The levels elasticity derivation is pretty similar.

Comment: My derivation is correct, elasticity is dQ/dp * p/Q, not just dQ/dp.